# SQL Server query combine cursor output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-cursor

I want to combine the output of this query in one table, what should i use join/union or something else?

```sql
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      select getdate() as [Date Time], DEFAULT_DOMAIN()[Domain], SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS Server,@@servername as [Instance],@name AS [Database], *
      from sys.sysprocesses  

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Combine how? A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Do you, perhaps, think that the above query will iterate through each of the databases on your instance? It won't. Effectively it'll run the same query against the **same** databases many times; once for the number of databases you have, but the database queried won't differ.

Comment: Also, why are you using `sys.sysprocesses` and `sys.sysdatabases`? Those tables are for compatibility with SQL Server **2000** databases. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Why would you use a cursor (or any loop) to do this?  It's an order of magnitude easier (and *faster*) to just use a single query.  Heck, there isn't even a `WHERE` clause on the inner query, so it's just going to return the same thing in every "row".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can be solved using a variable table and temp table. I used a variable table you can add as many columns as you want.

```sql
DECLARE @process_table TABLE (
    [Date Time] datetime  NULL,
    Domain varchar(max) NULL,
     [Server] sql_variant NULL,
      Instance varchar(max) NULL,
       [Database] varchar(max) NULL 
);

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      Insert into @process_table([Date Time],Domain,[Server],Instance,[Database])
      select getdate() as [Date Time], DEFAULT_DOMAIN()[Domain], SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS Server,@@servername as [Instance],@name AS [Database]
      from sys.sysprocesses

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

Select * from @process_table
```

Comment: This'll have the same problem I mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433924/sql-server-query-combine-cursor-output#comment124506041_70433924) though; it'll run the *same* query against the **same database** many times. What's the point in that? If you want a query with one row per database, you might as well use a `CROSS JOIN` and bin the `CURSOR`.

Comment: It will push rows of each database process in one table I think this is what is asked in question!

Comment: *"It will push rows of each database process"* Wrong. It will "push" the rows of **one** database's processes to one table *many* times; and the value in the `Database` column would just change each time. And, again, if you wanted that, you might as well `CROSS JOIN` to `sys.databases` (not `sys.sysdatabases`, [like I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433924/sql-server-query-combine-cursor-output/70434376?noredirect=1#comment124506075_70433924) too).

Comment: i want to put the output of the different tables in one table, maybe something with WHILE LOOP?

Comment: You need to explain what you *really* want in the query, @Rednirug .

Comment: I want the domain, server, instance and database as default properties and then include the processes, of if i request propertie of one database i get the resultset of the processes with it in

Comment: @Larnu Only database not getting change their process also getting changed. supposed it's not getting then how cross joins solve this problem, Lets understand what actually he is looking for.

Comment: its very simple what i want, i just want the processes of the instance behind each database, even if the processes are duplicated behind the database. So you will have domain, server, instance and database as default and then the processes behind it. My output is separated in different tables because of the databases.

Comment: @Shahab you should not assume someone's gender. There is nothing in Rednirug's profile or question(s) to state they are male, and the Code of Conduct explicitly states to use gender neutral language unless they ask otherwise.